# JQuery & cloning huge table

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a huge table, 1 row with around 2600 columns (it's a Gantt chart)

What I'm trying to do is to clone this table and copy it 100 times to somewhere on the page (instead of redraw the table 100 times as it seems to be less efficient, I can be wrong though)

```
var $templateTable = $("div#GTT_TLayout").clone();
//there are 100 divs matching it
$("div[id ^= 'taskgrid_bar_' ]").each(function(){  
    ...
    $(this).before($templateTable.html());
});
```

The issue is that some customers experience this "script time out" issue.

So the question I have is, is there a better way to do this that is more efficient?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried passing just `$templateTable` to `before()` without calling `.html()`?

Comment: I know this is incredibly off tangent, but if you're working with something that big, and if client side scripts are too slow, then surely the logical next step is moving to a server side script?

Comment: @Pointy, tried that and for some reasons, it's not generating the tables 

and @Yi Jiang, tried that as well. However, the performance is even worse than the JQuery way. Even though, eventually, it will generate, but very slow. I can see as each row generates one row at a time. The upside is that it guarantees the chart will be generated.

Comment: Well, another thing to maybe try is to change things so that instead of dropping copies of the table separately into those other elements, you rebuild that entire portion of the page (divs and all) as a big string value, and then update the DOM all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well do the `.html()` call on the `$templateTable` outside of the `.each` since there is no point in calling that 100 times.  That should help a little anyways.

Comment: Good point @amurra. Tried it out, improved a little, still cause issues depending on the pc. :(